# d3.js - detect circles with the same center

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a problem with detecting circles with the same center point. I have N circles on plot.Some of that circles can have exactly the same position(x,y) of center. I want to indicate it, by showing for example "+1" inside that circle.

I would like to ask you if you know how to achieve it? How can I detect which of data elements are exactly at the same position? I don't want to compare each of point to another, hope there is better solution.

For now generating circles based on data looks like this.

```
this.svg
      .selectAll('circle')
      .data(this.data.suppliers)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .classed('chart-item', true)
      .style('fill', function(supplier, idx) {
        return 'red';
      })
      .attr('cx', supplier => {
        if (supplier.x) return this.xScale(supplier.x);
        else return 0;
      })
      .attr('cy', supplier => {
        if (supplier.y) return this.yScale(supplier.y);
        else return 0;
      })
      .attr('r', supplier => {
          return 10;
        }
      })
      //HIGHLIGHT selected supplier
      .classed('highlighted', supplier => {
        if (
          supplier.id === this.data.selectedSupplier.id &&
          supplier.id === this.data.selectedSupplier.id
        ) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
      // .select(function(supplier){that.showTooltip({left:120,top:120},supplier)})
      .on('mousemove', function(supplier) {
        that.handleMouseMove(this, supplier);
      })
      .on('mouseout', function() {
        that.handleMouseOut(this);
      });
```

Comment: perhaps the collide functionality may come in handy here

Comment: Sorry my last list wasnt correct, check here : http://bl.ocks.org/ahmohamed/c1804b03b71d8a17bd37, perhaps you could work with this to check for overlap, and if two nodes overlap, increase the count on the lable (if no overlap, dont show label), and youll only see the one in front

Comment: create a dictionary with the already know positions as keys, test a new circle position if that keys is already known, if yes increment dict value otherwise add key to dict with value 0

Comment: @Mateusz do you still need an answer to this?

Comment: I think yes. Soon I will try to implement @rioV8 answer